# Matplotlib - Series of curves on with individual markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a series of curves on the same graph with individual markers:

- Each curve has one colour
- Each data point has its own markers

For this, I created 3 lists of lists: `x_data`, `y_data` and `markers`. Using `np.array()`, `x_data` and `y_data` can be plotted properly as different curves (with individual colours).

However, `np.array()` cannot be used with the attribute `marker` and I do not know how to pass `markers` to `ax.plot()`.

Does someone know how to attribute individual markers?

**MWE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_data=[[1,2,3,4,5],[5,10,3,8,6]]
y_data=[[5,10,3,8,6],[1,2,3,4,5]]
markers=[["o","+","D","+","D"],["D","o","o","D","+"]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for n in range(0,len(x_data)):
    ax.plot(np.array(x_data[n]), np.array(y_data[n]),linewidth=1,marker=np.array(markers))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is an inner loop to scatter plot each marker individually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_data=[[1,2,3,4,5],[5,10,3,8,6]]
y_data=[[5,10,3,8,6],[1,2,3,4,5]]
markers=[["o","+","D","+","D"],["D","o","o","D","+"]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for xs, ys, markers in zip(x_data, y_data, markers):
    line = ax.plot(xs, ys, linewidth=1)
    colour = line[0].get_color()
    for x, y, marker in zip(xs, ys, markers):
        ax.scatter(x, y, marker=marker, color=colour)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is very nice! In my complete code, I do not know how many curves I will have. Is there a way to define the curves colours automatically?

Comment: Yes, let me revise. I added the colours to ensure that the markers and lines are the same colour where applicable..